# how to close previous colorbox after redirecting to a new colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I am trying to open a new colorbox from a parent colorbox but the parent colorbox should be closed on redirecting to the new one. i have tried a lot search out contents in stack but not getting the solution.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#btnUpdate").click(function(){

            $.ajax({
                url:"cart.php",
                type:"post",
                data:$("#frmCart").serialize(),
                success:function(result){
                    alert('Product updated to cart!');  
                    $.colorbox({html:result});


                    },
                }); 
                parent.$.colorbox.close();
            });


        });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post the structure of your HTML related to #btnUpdate/ the colorboxes?

Comment: What happens if you don't close ?